# Android Studio Gradle programmatically find build type

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Would appreciate some help on this matter. I am currently trying to edit a file during pre-processing depending on what the selected build type is. I am aware of the buildTypes { } block. However for the time being let's say that this option is not viable. Is it possible to figure out what your current variant is programmatically in gradle?